# Remove espaços produzidos por quebras de linha

Tags: php

Porque o código abaixo não remove os espaços, somente as quebras de linha?

```
$urlCorreios = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?
   nCdEmpresa=&
   sDsSenha=&
   nCdFormato=1&
   nVlDiametro=0&
   sCdMaoPropria=n&
   sCdAvisoRecebimento=n&
   nCdServico=" . $cod_servico . "&
   sCepOrigem=" . $cep_origem . "&
   sCepDestino=" . $cep_destino . "&
   nVlPeso=" . $peso . "&
   nVlAltura=" . $altura . "&
   nVlLargura=" . $largura . "&
   nVlComprimento=" . $comprimento . "&
   nVlValorDeclarado=" . $valor_declarado . "&
   StrRetorno=xml";

echo preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]/', '', $urlCorreios);
```

Comment: Apenas complementando, você usou `[\n\r\t]`. Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), e corresponde a qualquer caractere que estão dentro deles. Então esta regex significa: "um `\n` **ou** um `\r` **ou** um `\t`". Nenhum desses caracteres corresponde ao espaço em branco :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E porque não simplesmente usar uma função nativa, como `http_build_query()`? Exemplo:

```
$urlCorreios = "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx";

$data = array(
    "nCdEmpresa" => "",
    "sDsSenha" => "",
    "nCdFormato" => "1",
    "nVlDiametro" => "0",
    "sCdMaoPropria" => "n",
    "sCdAvisoRecebimento" => "n",
    "nCdServico=" => $cod_servico,
    "sCepOrigem=" => $cep_origem,
    "sCepDestino=" => $cep_destino,
    "nVlPeso=" => $peso,
    "nVlAltura=" => $altura,
    "nVlLargura=" => $largura,
    "nVlComprimento=" => $comprimento,
    "nVlValorDeclarado=" => $valor_declarado,
    "StrRetorno" => "xml"
);

$urlCorreios = $urlCorreios . '?' . http_build_query($data);

echo $urlCorreios . "\n";
```

Outra vantagem sobre isto é que não precisaria fazer `urlencode()` de valores e chaves, fora que vai ficar mais fácil do que ficar usando string e vai poder manipular o array a hora que desejar com funções nativas de array no PHP.

Outra coisa, usar `\s`, como está na outra resposta, sem tratar variável por variável com `urlencode` (acaso não use `http_build_query`) vai dar problema com certeza, se bem que só o não uso de `urlencode` já seria um problema.

Comment: Caramba nunca tinha visto essa função http_build_query() e já tive alguns problemas com quebra de linha, obrigado pela dica mano.

Answer (score 2):

Tente adicionar um `\s` no regex. Assim:

`echo preg_replace('/[\s\n\r\t]/', '', $urlCorreios);`

Comment: `\s` já engloba o `\n`, `\r` e `\t`, então poderia ser somente `preg_replace('/\s/', '', $urlCorreios)`

Comment: ok. muitio obrigado!

Comment: @hkotsubo exatamente, é redundante. Nem mesmo é necessário o `[...]`, bastaria algo como `'/\s+?/'`